# Dilemma with hashCode() - Java

Tags: java, object, hashcode

I have the following code,

```
Object testA =  new Object();
Object testB = testA;
System.out.println("A:"+testA.hashCode())
System.out.println("B:"+testB.hashCode())
```

Per the above, I get the same hashcode for the two objects. I understand that testB is assigned testA and so it could have the same hashcode, however there should be a way to uniquely identify the difference in both these objects right?

Please let me know if there is something obvious that am missing!

Answer (score 7):

> however there should be a way to uniquely identify the difference in both these objects right?

There is no difference, since there are no two objects. There is just one object referred by two variables.

In theory, two different objects may have the same `hashCode`. You can tell them apart by using `equals` or by using `==`. If you don't override `equals`, it behaves as `==` by default.

Answer (score 4):

The `hashCode` function [has to be compatible with the `equals` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) in the sense that `hashCode` has to return the same value for 2 objects that are equal. In this case, they are not only "equal" (according to the `equals` method), but even the *same* object (which implies that they are equal).

Besides, independently of what the specification demands, it would impossible for the 2 calls to `hashCode` to return different values because both variables are actually referencing the same object. There is no way to distinguish `testA` and `testB` (apart from the variable name, of course).

Comment: Upon checking the == operator, it will say that it is equal.

Comment: @Faz: The relevant part for `hashCode` is the `equals` method, not `==`. But in this case, *both* will say they are equal.

Comment: Can you add a reference to a Java doc or something which says hashcode is expected to be same if equals method returns true???

Answer (score 1):

You create a new object testA but then assign testB to testA, which assigns the same memory space for both of the objects. This is why its returning the same HashCode.